# mysql_fetch_array with conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a soccer site. I have the following table structure:

```
season1 (name of the table)
id | player1 | player2 | score
```

I want to put the scores into a html table. This table is only for player called nickname1 vs every other player. I have this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM season1 WHERE player1='nickname1'") or die(mysql_error());  

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo "";
    echo "</td><td>";   
    echo $row['score2'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['score3']; 
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['score4'];  
    echo "</td><td>";   
    echo $row['score5'];  
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table> <br>";
```

- Instead of $row['score2'] I need the score between nickname1 vs
  nickname2
- Instead of $row['score3'] I need the score between    nickname1 vs
  nickname3
- Instead of $row['score4'] I need the score    between nickname1 vs
  nickname4
- Instead of $row['score5'] I need the    score between nickname1 vs
  nickname5

I tried `SELECT * FROM season1 WHERE player1='nickname1' AND player2='nickname2'` but then it will show only player1 vs player2 in the table. I want to show all 4 players vs player1 in the same table.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

You need to focus your loop only on making one row:

```
echo "<table><tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
    echo "<td>{$row['score']}</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

This will ONLY output the scores of the players. You can modify it to have nickname headers and so forth.

Take note that the `$row` array resembles your table structure. `$row['score']` will give you the scores of the players where as since `score1` is not a column in the table, it does not exist in `$row`.

Possible design:

```
echo "<table><tr><th>Player 1</th><th>Player 2</th><th>Score</th></tr><tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
    echo "<td>{$row['player1']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['player2']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['score']}</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

will output (depending on ID's in database)

```
Player 1  |  Player 2 |  Score
   p1           p2         0
   p1           p3         0
```

**NOTICE:** MySQL_* has been deprecated in PHP 5.5. Use MySQLi or PDO instead

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I want to post the stats for player1 vs all other players. I have a html table with p1vsp2, p1vsp3, p1vsp4. That means that in the first column (p1vsp2) I need something like "if mysql column called player2 has the word nickname2 post the score" and so on.

Comment: Will `p1 vs p2` always have a lower `ID` in the database than `p1 vs p3`? If so, then doesn't my table example cover what you want? If not, how do you know who p2 is?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming score1 it's player 1 score:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM season1 WHERE player1='nickname1'") or die(mysql_error());  

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo "";
echo "</td><td>";   
echo $row['player1']." vs ".$row['player2'].", with a score of: ".$row['score'];
echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table> <br>";
```

I hope it helps.

Saludos ;)

Comment: $row['score1'], $row['score2'] do not exists. I have just written them there to explain it better. It's only "score" for all players. So I need something like "if column player2 has the word nickname2 post the score".